# Ruby/Rails: Determining Comparator At Runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a Rails project which executes queries against databases and then compares the results to conditions specified by the user. The meat of this error detection process can be summed up like this:

```
case error_operator
  when '<'
    if results.row_count < desired_row_count
      then # do error-related stuff 
      else # do other stuff
    end
  when '<='
    if results.row_count <= desired_row_count
      then # do error-related stuff 
      else # do other stuff
    end
  when '>'
    if results.row_count > desired_row_count
      then # do error-related stuff 
      else # do other stuff
    end
  when '>='
    if results.row_count >= desired_row_count
      then # do error-related stuff 
      else # do other stuff
    end
  when '!='
    if results.row_count != desired_row_count
      then # do error-related stuff 
      else # do other stuff
    end
  when '=='
    if results.row_count == desired_row_count
      then # do error-related stuff 
      else # do other stuff
    end
  end
```

The error_operator variable is stored in Rails as a string as a property of the task object, so each task might have a different comparator. Is there a way to get Ruby to recognize that a given string can be parsed as a comparator? I'm open to storing the comparator for a given task differently as well, if that's an option. I didn't write the original code, so I'm not married to it.

Thanks!

Comment: Confused about what you need. Does converting the string to a symbol and looking for it in `Integer.instance_methods` not work (since that's the class of a `row_count`'s return value)?

Comment: After learning more about how "everything is an object in Ruby" I was able to invoke results.row_count.method(error_operator).(desired_row_count) and have that work. Now the comparison is done with the comparator determined at runtime.

Comment: If you just need to map strings to method calls, you could shorten your code further by just `send`ing the string and argument to the integer in question and skip instantiating the method: `results.row_count.send(error_operator, desired_row_count)`.

In Ruby, you can largely think of traditional method calls as syntax sugar for `send`ing the method name + arguments to an object.